# Hola, gente tengo un tema con un error que me sale en mi pagina

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in /www/soportemurl.com/htdocs/support/connection.php:112 Stack trace: #0 /www/soportemurl.com/htdocs/support/index.php(57): DB->count('articles', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /www/soportemurl.com/htdocs/support/connection.php on line 112

*Lo Mas raro es que en XAMPP me va perfecto este código pero al subirlo al host no :(*

**Aca dejo el código para el que me pueda ayudar plis**

```
        public function count($tbl, $where = []) {
            $sql = "SELECT count(*) as `count` FROM `$tbl` ";
            if (!empty($where)) {
                if (is_array($where)) {
                    $arrWhere = [];
                    foreach ($where as $field => $val) {
                        $arrWhere[] = " `$field` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $val) . "' ";
                    }
                    $sql .= "WHERE 1 AND" . implode(" AND ", $arrWhere);
                } else {
                    $sql .= "WHERE 1 AND " . $where;
                }
            }
            $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
            $rs = $rs->fetch_object();    //Aca supuestamente esta el error
            return $rs->count;
        }
```

Comment: Recomiendo revisar la version de MySql que tienes en tu local y en tu host. Para descartar un problema de compatbilidad.

Comment: Imprime la consulta con `echo $sql;` cópiala y pégala en PHPMyAdmin (o el manejador de base de datos que tengas), seguramente ahí verás el error. Si no, edita la pregunta y pega aquí mismo la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera es debuggearlo por ti mismo...
Para ello puedes agregar var_dump() en las lineas que causan problemas.

- La sentencia generada
- al resultado mismo

De este modo: (Luego te mostrará que sale mal y porqué)

---

En tu caso, claramente dice que estás cargando un booleano, por lo que la sentencia debe fallar en cierto punto.

```
public function count($tbl, $where = []) {
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as `count` FROM `$tbl` ";
    if (!empty($where)) {
        if (is_array($where)) {
            $arrWhere = [];
            foreach ($where as $field => $val) {
                $arrWhere[] = " `$field` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $val) . "' ";
            }
           $sql .= "WHERE 1 AND" . implode(" AND ", $arrWhere);
        } else {
           $sql .= "WHERE 1 AND " . $where;
        }
        var_dump($sql);
    }
    $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
    var_dump($rs);
    $rs = $rs->fetch_object();    //Aca supuestamente esta el error
    return $rs->count;
}
```